# Texto e inputs na mesma linha

Tags: html

Preciso colocar um texto, um input-text, outro texto e outro input text na mesma linha (row) em html. Não consigo encontrar uma maneira.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não entendi sua duvida? você quer colocar `label` e `input` um do lado do outro?

Comment: Teria um exemplo de como vc esta fazendo?

Comment: `<table><tr><td>texto <input type="text"><input type="text"></td></tr></table>`

Answer (score 2):

Você pode colocar um label na frente do seu input, ficando assim:

```html
<label>Nome: </label><input type="text" name="nome">
<label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email">
```

Caso queira colocar um input em baixo de outro, você coloca um br pra quebrar a linha.

Answer (score 2):

com um simples CSS

```css
#inline {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="inline">
   um texto <input type="text" placeholder="um input"/>
   outro texto <input type="text" placeholder="outro input"/>
</div>
```